# UPDATE MYSQL CON PHP

Tags: php, mysql

estoy intentando hacer un update en mysql desde php, pero me está resultando difícil, puesto que quiero recoger los valores de un formulario en el que sus nombres están puestos con el nombre de los campos de las columnas, no me se explicar muy bien, os paso código:

```
<body>
<div align="center" style="font-size:40px">
    <form method="post" action="aceptar-edicion.php">
        <fieldset style="width:70%">
            <legend>Editar marca</legend>
            <?php
            ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

                        // Valor por defecto en PHP
                        // Muestra todos los errores menos las notificaciones
                        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

                        // Muestro todos los errores
                        error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
                        error_reporting(E_ALL);
                        error_reporting(-1);

                        // Muestro todos los errores, incluso los estrictos
                        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

                        // No muestra ningún error
                        error_reporting(0);

                        // También se puede usar la función ini_set
                        ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);


                     //// Recoger variables ////

                    $marca = $_POST['marca'];

                    ////Datos db
                    $usuario = "usuario";
                    $password = "pass";
                    $servidor = "server";
                    $basededatos = "bd";

                    ////Crear conexion
                    $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password)
                    or die("No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

                    ////Seleccionar db
                    $db = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos)
                    or die("Uppppss! No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

                    ////Establecer y realizar consulta

                    $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM marcas";

                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

                    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){

                        echo "<label>" . ($fila['Field']) . "   " . "<input type='text' name='" . $fila['Field'] . "' id='" . $fila['Field'] . "'</label></br>";

                    }//end while

                    ////Cerrar conexion 
                    mysqli_close($conexion);
            ?>
            </br>
            <input type="submit" value="Aceptar cambio"/>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Como podéis ver, quiero hacer labels con sus respectivos inputs poniendo el nombre de cada columna de la tabla mysql. Es decir, si tengo las columnas en mi tabla "nombre,direccion,telefono,email" quiero que salga un label con ese valor y un input a su lado con el "name" y el "id" llamados como el campo, hasta ahí bien.

Ahora, quiero recoger los valores de esos input y meterlos en una tabla ya creada, pero no sabría cómo hacerla, porque tendría que leer de nuevo las columnas de la tabla.

```
<body>
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

        // Valor por defecto en PHP
        // Muestra todos los errores menos las notificaciones
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

        // Muestro todos los errores
        error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        error_reporting(-1);

        // Muestro todos los errores, incluso los estrictos
        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

        // No muestra ningún error
        error_reporting(0);

        // También se puede usar la función ini_set
        ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);


     //// Recoger variables ////

    $marca = $_POST['marca'];

    ////Datos db
    $usuario = "usuario";
    $password = "pass";
    $servidor = "server";
    $basededatos = "bd";

    ////Crear conexion
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password)
    or die("No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

    ////Seleccionar db
    $db = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos)
    or die("Uppppss! No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

    ////Establecer y realizar consulta
    ////////////////////////AQUÍ ES DONDE NO SE QUÉ HACER//////////////////////////
    $sql = "UPDATE marcas SET ";
    for($i=0; $i<= ; $i++){
        echo $fila[$i] . " = '" . $_POST[$fila[$i]] . "', ";
        }
        echo " WHERE nombre = " . $marca . ";"; 

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);


    ////Cerrar conexion 
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

No se como podría hacerlo , me resulta muy dificil, espero que me podáis ayudar, gracias.

Comment: En tu código hay error, no has especificado el valor de $i en tu bucle

Comment: Cuando tú cargas una página que tiene un formulario y/u otro contenido, eso **debería ocurrir *del lado del cliente***, mientras eso ocurre, tú no ocupas para nada al servidor, lo cual es bueno, porque de ocuparlo estarías consumiendo recursos y la carga podría ser más lenta. Yo preguntaría entonces, ¿por qué quieres usar la base de datos, recargando al servidor, para hacer algo que podrías hacer totalmente en el cliente? Recomendaría que escribas tu formulario *a mano* y totalmente del lado del cliente, que dejes al servidor tranquilo en ese caso, usándolo solamente para el `UPDATE`.

Comment: @outman si si, porque lo dejé ahí, aunque ponga algo no funcionaría. Tampoco se si haciendo un bucle funcionaría, solo enseño hasta donde lo dejé para ver si alguin me ayuda con eso o proponiéndome otra forma de hacer lo que necesito.

Comment: Como he dicho hay más errores por ejemplo no has cerrado el tag input yo coincido con @A.Cedano pero lo que quieres es solucionar tu problema, primero la consulta de UPDATE esta mal, de hecho si de donde viene el variable $fila[]?

Comment: @A.Cedano Porque en el proyecto que estoy haciendo, tengo un formulario en el que puedo añadir o eliminar campos de mi tabla desde el propio formulario, enotnces quiero que los label e inputs se vayan actualizando solos , leyendo los campos de la tabla.

Comment: @outman cierto, el tag de input no está puesto, pero eso es fácil, a lo que me refiero con esta pregunta es otra cosa, que no sabría hacer el update para mysql.

Comment: Bueno, ese sería ¿quizá? el único caso en que tal proceder sería justificado. En cuanto a la otra parte del código, generalmente los datos de un formulario se envían serializados en un array cuya clave es igual a la etiqueta `name` de cada `input` y el valor es el dato que se ha escrito en el `input`. Entonces, haciendo un recorrido de `_$POST`, que no es otra cosa que un array, tú puedes obtener tanto los valores como las llaves, mediante algo como esto: `foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v){  //aquí $k será el nombre de cada campo y $v será su valor ...}` eso suponiendo ...

Comment: ... que no haya otros valores extraños al `UPDATE` dentro del formulario (de ser así, puedes hacer grupos de valores mediante la etiqueta `fieldset`). A continuación, podrías asignar cada `SET`
  con su respectivo campo y valor de una forma dinámica. No obstante, esta forma es altamente vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL. Para blindar el código, deberías aplicar consultas preparadas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Entonces como se supone que sería el código para realizar el update?Porque habría que hacer, suspuestamente, un bucle, en el cual la longitud no sabría cómo calcularla, porque como ya te dije, podia añadir o eliminar los campos de la tabla. ¿Sabrías de alguna otra manera hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Como te dije en comentarios, `POST` crea un array asociativo en el que la clave equivale a la etiqueta `name` de cada `input`, mientras que el valor es el valor escrito en él.

Entonces, tú podrías leer ese array y setear los valores.

Aunque en tu código no parece cumplirse lo que dices, pues la columna `marca` tú la igualas a un supuesto input name igual a `nombre`. He escrito el código en ese sentido, pero debes prestar atención a cómo se llama esa columna realmente en tu tabla, porque el funcionamiento correcto dependerá de ello.

Sería algo así:

```
$arrPost=$_POST;
$marca=$POST_["marca"];

$sql="UPDATE marcas SET ";
foreach ($arrPost as $k=>$v){
    /*Se supone que la columna marca no entra en los SET*/
    if($k!="nombre"){
        $sql.=$k."='".$v."'";   
    }   
}
$sql.=" WHERE nombre = '" . $marca . "'";
```

> **NOTA:** Este código es vulnerable a Inyección SQL. Se ha escrito esta respuesta respondiendo a los requerimientos del OP. Conviene en
>   este caso aplicar consultas preparadas para prevenir los ataques de
>   Inyección SQL.